# Postfix: how to redirect a single email address depending on the sender

Tags: postfix, redirection, smtp-headers

I'm trying to add a rule to Postfix.

My goal is as follows: when anyone EXCEPT (server@example.com) sends an email to (info@example.com) forward it to (sales@example.com).  If server@example.com is sending the mail, simply allow it to flow through. 
To recap, if the sender is NOT server@example.com, redirect the message to sales@example.com.  If the sender IS server@example.com, do not redirect.

FYI, info@example.com is an alias, defined in /etc/postfix/virtual which sends to several recipients.

I am using pcre header_checks, but it's simply not working - nothing is happening and all mail is flowing as it was before without being redirected.

If there is a better/easier way to do this, I'm all ears!

So per the instructions in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/284702/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660818/) I added the following lines to main.cf and headers_check:

main.cf:

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/headers_check
```

/etc/postfix/headers_check

```
/To:info@example.com/ && /From:(?(?!server@example.com).)*/ REDIRECT sales@example.com
```

However, nothing happens.  All mail still gets dropped into info@example.com.  I removed the 'From' check to see if I could just grab all messages sent to info@example.com and redirect.  However, this didn't work either. 
I ran

```
postmap -q "From:server@example.com\nTo:info@example.com" pcre:/etc/postfix/headers_check
```

and received the response

```
&& /(?(?!server@example.com).)*/ REDIRECT sales@example.com
```

I also restarted postfix (postfix reload) to ensure it had loaded the configuration.

Also, please note that this is a machine having lots of virtual hosts, each with its own email addresses and aliases.  All are combined in /etc/postfix/virtual.

Thanks for any advice on how to accomplish this!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/284900/218590) was accepted and upvoted.[Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) clearly states that postfix only examines one header line at a time.

> These rules operate on one logical message header or one body line at a time. A decision made for one line is not carried over to the next line.

So, your idea to combine **From** and **To** header isn't supported by Postfix.

---

The other way is using envelope address instead address in email header. To do this you can use postfix feature called restriction classes. See

- http://www.postfix.net/postconf.5.html#smtpd_restriction_classes
- http://www.postfix.net/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html.

In main.cf add this line

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = specialsender
specialsender = permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    ...
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/mycompany.redirection,
    check_recipient_access  hash:/etc/postfix/redirect.sales
    ...
```

Content of `/etc/postfix/mycompany.redirection`

```
server@example.com     specialsender
```

Content of `/etc/postfix/redirect.sales`

```
info@example.com      REDIRECT sales@example.com
```

#### How it works

When postfix encounter this line

```
check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/mycompany.redirection
```

and found out that server@example.com in specialsender class, then postfix permit it without redirect. Another email address will be checked against

```
check_recipient_access  /etc/postfix/redirect.sales
```

And if recipient == info@example.com, it will be redirected to sales@example.com