# Redirect mails to a different recipient

Tags: postfix, redirect

We have a server which is sending sheduled mails to an address which does not exists. This was a false configuration by a former coworker and we are unable to detect where it happens.

So our idea was to redirect on our MailRelay every mail that is send to this address to a different one.

We already tried with virtual aliases, but this causes issues for other services which also uses the Relay Server.

Also simple `header_checks`, like described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/284702/redirect-specific-e-mail-address-sent-to-a-user-to-another-user) disturb our other communication.

What we are looking for:

Behave as configured, except the mail is going to "false_configured@our-domain.com".

LOGEDIT:

```bash
Feb 21 17:39:55 mairel postfix/qmgr[261314]: F10D22005C: from=<xwiki-server@our-domain>, size=23309, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 21 17:39:55 mairel postfix/smtp[263664]: fatal: valid hostname or network address required in server description: admin@our-domain.com
Feb 21 17:39:56 mairel postfix/qmgr[261314]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
Feb 21 17:39:56 mairel postfix/qmgr[261314]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
Feb 21 17:39:56 mairel postfix/master[261312]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtp pid 263664 exit status 1
Feb 21 17:39:56 mairel postfix/error[263667]: F10D22005C: to=<false_configured@our-domain.com>, relay=none, delay=134869, delays=134868/1/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
```

This is filling up the logfile since I tried @Turdie approach.

Just to mention, all our servers connects to this mailrelay and the mail relay connects to the official Access Mail Relay.

Comment: I was incorrect sorry, but I found this https://serverfault.com/a/284900/145902

Comment: No issue, I also found the header filter approach, but sadly this also only works if the server is handling the mail transport and not the gateway. This approach blocked all other incoming mails on the gateway.